# Clang-format inserts a new line before function argument for no reason

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, clang++, clang-format

I am building clang-format from source because I want to have custom Passes for formatting, which is working as intended, but I experienced a weird behavior that even the current (LLVM 11) binaries produce.

Given the following code:

```
connect(this->meta(),
        &details::IDeviceControlServiceBaseMeta::directCommuncationTested,
        this->meta(),
        [this](auto result) {
            // some stuff
        },
        Qt::DirectConnection);
```

Clang-format inserts a new line before the first parameter resulting this:

```
connect(
        this->meta(),
        &details::IDeviceControlServiceBaseMeta::directCommuncationTested,
        this->meta(),
        [this](auto result) {
            // some stuff    
        },
        Qt::DirectConnection);
```

I could not find the code in the clang-format source that results in behavior, nor any configuration option solved my problem.

I think the "problem" is somewhere in the `clang/lib/Format/ContinuationIndenter.cpp` file but I couldnt find it.

Any help is appreciated.

Edit: This only happens with LLVM-8 and upwards, with LLVM-7 it is working as I expected, but I need this to work with version 11 or maybe 10.

Edit2: I created a bug ticket just in case : https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=48996

Comment: Have you considered opening a bug report?

Comment: @SebastianRedl Not yet since I am not certain that it is a bug. I also asked this question on the dedicated Discord server. I will wait a day or two to get some confirmation, then Ill open a bug ticket

Comment: If there was a way to avoid that, I would have expected `PenaltyBreakBeforeFirstCallParameter` to help. It didn't work in my testing. Personally, I prefer the new style (whether intentional or not) since it allows consistent indent for argument lists. Changing of the style between versions without touching configuration does smell of bug though.

Comment: @eerorika yes it might actually be bug, even if the entire lambda expression is a one liner, it still inserts a new line, but if I swap out the lambda expression for a member function reference, it formats correctly